# Can we access the output from a replicateM defined in a do-block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, do-notation

Assume i have something like this

```
main = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int

    replicateM n $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let x = read input_line :: Int 

        return ()

 ***putStrLn $ show -- Can i access my replicateM here?
    return ()
```

Can i access the result of my replicateM such as if it was a returned value, and for example print it out. Or do i have to work with the replicateM inside the actual do-block?

Comment: `readLn` is superior to `getLine`+`read`, because it throws an `IO` error immediately if you get text that isn't `read`able rather than waiting until some indeterminate later date when the value is used to throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specialized to `IO`

```
replicateM :: Int -> IO a -> IO [a]
```

which means that it returns a list.    So in your example you could do:

```
results <- replicateM n $ do
    input_line <- getLine
    let x = read input_line :: Int
    return x   -- <- we have to return it if we want to access it

print results
```

Answer (score 3):

`replicateM n a` returns a list of the values returned by `a`. In your case that'd just be a list of units because you have the `return ()` at the end, but if you replace that with `return x`, you'll get a list of the read integers. You can then just use `<-` to get it out of the `IO`.

You can also simplify your code by using `readLine` instead of `getLine` and `read`. Similarly `putStrLn . show` can be replaced with `print`.

```
main = do
    n <- readLn
    ints <- replicateM n readLn :: IO [Int]
    print ints
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Its type is `replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`. It means it can appear to the right of `<-` in a `do` block:

```
    do
        ....
        xs <- replicateM n $ do { ... }
        ....
```

`xs` will be of type `[a]`, as usual for binding the results from `Monad m => m [a]`.

With your code though, where you show `return ()` in that nested `do`, you'll get  `()`s replicated `n` times in your `xs`. Presumably in the real code you will `return` something useful there.